# Add Column from 1 table to Another

Tags: sql-server

I have a table
 `contracts` and a table `company`.
I have data in `company` in a column titled `type_id` and I want to create a new column in `contracts` called `company_type` joining the data from `company.type_id` into `contracts.company_type`

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
--create new column
--adjust data type to match data type in company table
ALTER TABLE contracts
ADD company_type VARCHAR(100)

--company_type is now null for all rows in contracts
--update data with script below
UPDATE t
SET t.company_type = p.company_type
FROM contracts t
INNER JOIN company p ON t.type_id = p.type_id
```